# How can I solve this: <class 'website.admin.UserProfileInline'>: (admin.E202) 'website.Profile' has no ForeignKey to 'website.Doctor'?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I do not really know whatI'm doing wrong>
I have some ForeignKeys relatinships in my models which I would like to display in the admin site on my forms. I'm trying to display my ForeignKeys and display in the django admin site but I'm receiving the following error:

```
<class 'website.admin.UserProfileInline'>: (admin.E202) 'website.Profile' has no ForeignKey to 'website.Doctor'.
```

Here're my models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICE_MALE = 'M'
    SEX_CHOICE_FEMALE = 'F'

    SEX_CHOICES = (
        (SEX_CHOICE_MALE, "Male"),
        (SEX_CHOICE_FEMALE, "Female")
        )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    initial = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='N/A')
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    postcode = models.IntegerField(default=0000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    health_history = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Appointment(models.Model):
    TIME_SLOT = (
        (1, _("8h00 - 8h30")),
        (2, _("8h30 - 9h00")),
        (3, _("9h00 - 9h30")),
        (4, _("9h30 - 10h00")),
        (5, _("10h00 - 10h30")),
        (6, _("10h30 - 11h00")),
        (7, _("11h00 - 11h30")),
        (7, _("11h30 - 12h00")),
    )

    STATUS_INACTIVE = 'I'
    STATUS_ACTIVE = 'A'

    STATUS = (
        (STATUS_ACTIVE, "Acitve"),
        (STATUS_INACTIVE, "Innactive")
    )

    APPOINTMMENT_TYPE_ONLINE = 'O'
    APPOINTMMENT_TYPE_PHYSICAL = 'P'

    APPOINTMMENT_TYPE = (
        (APPOINTMMENT_TYPE_ONLINE, "Online"),
        (APPOINTMMENT_TYPE_PHYSICAL, "Physical")
    )

    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default=STATUS_ACTIVE,max_length=7)
    slot = models.CharField(default=1, choices=TIME_SLOT, max_length=10)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor')
    patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient')
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    reason = models.TextField()
    showed_up = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    appointment_type = models.CharField(default=APPOINTMMENT_TYPE_PHYSICAL, max_length=10)
    consultation = models.ForeignKey("Consultation")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date


class Consultation(models.Model):
    diagnosis = models.TextField()
    prescription = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self


class Account(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient')
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Due to us', max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient
```

and my admin.py:

```
from .models import (Account, Appointment, Consultation, Department, Doctor,
                     Profile, Patient)
try:
    admin.site.unregister(User)
finally:
    class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = Profile

    @admin.register(Department)
    class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []

    # @admin.register(Profile)
    # class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #     fields = []

    @admin.register(Doctor)
    class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []
        inlines = [UserProfileInline]


    @admin.register(Patient)
    class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []

    @admin.register(Appointment)
    class AppointmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []

    @admin.register(Consultation)
    class ConsultationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []

    @admin.register(Account)
    class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 4):

Error description says everything:

```
'website.Profile' has no ForeignKey to 'website.Doctor'
```

You have two possibilities:

1. Add ForeignKey to Profile model: `doctor = models.OneToOneField(Doctor)`
2. Remove `inlines = [UserProfileInline]` from `DoctorAdmin` class

**EDIT**

Better choice is make `Profile` models abstract and inherit `Patient` and `Doctor` models from `Profile`.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICE_MALE = 'M'
    SEX_CHOICE_FEMALE = 'F'

    SEX_CHOICES = (
        (SEX_CHOICE_MALE, "Male"),
        (SEX_CHOICE_FEMALE, "Female")
        )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    initial = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='N/A')
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    postcode = models.IntegerField(default=0000)

    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Patient(Profile):
    health_history = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Doctor(Profile):
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**admin.py**

```
    @admin.register(Doctor)
    class DoctorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []


    @admin.register(Patient)
    class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = []
```

Comment: that's what I do not really get. I created the Profile models in order for the Doctor and Patient to inherit from since they all have many fields in common.